# Custom Sharepoint WCF - Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have a custom Sharepoint WCF Service that does database calls using ADO.NET.

I have tried just about everything I can, but everytime I call the SqlConnection.Open() method, I get this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not
>   provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

Things I've tried: 
New WCF Service,New database, different Connection Strings, hard code connection strings, all produce the same exception

My code sample below:

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    string _connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"; 

    SqlConnection dbConnection;
    SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter;
    SqlCommand dbCommand;
    DataTable dtResults;

    dbConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    dbCommand = new SqlCommand("GetTest", dbConnection);
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
    dtResults = new DataTable("Results");

    try
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        dbAdapter.Fill(dtResults);
        return dtResults.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error actually has nothing to do with your service itself. It's a permissions problem.

The issue is outlined here: [Could not load file or assembly System.EnterpriseServices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/07/11/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-enterpriseservices.aspx)

Essentially, the Claims Service Account needs the "Act as part of the Operating System" policy ([Act as part of the operating system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784323%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)), and then you need to restart the Claims to Windows Token Service and perform an IIS Reset.

Should work smooth as butter after that.